# Jmeter - Russian Characters Encoding Issue

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have an issue with scripting sites that are in dual language - English and Russian.

With Jmeter I post requests to fill a form containing both english and Russian characters, and when I check the application manually, I notice weird ???? symbols everywhere the russian characters are supposed to be.[image]

I have added the utf-8 encoding in jmeter.properties.
sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8

Please help suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix sorted the error :

In the http sampler request, input **utf-8**(in small characters) against the **Content-encoding** text window.

Content-Encoding : utf-8

Version: Jmeter 5.2.1 
(Left the Port number empty)

Answer (score -1):

Добавь в jmeter.properties который находится в папке \bin, через notepad например sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8 и будет тебе чудо.
Также доп в запросе (HTTP request) в поле Content encoding вписал utf-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StbVG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3tl8.png)